# Protractor test case for greater than 100 but passing string from html

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine

How to change the string to integer in Protractor. We are unable to know the problem, it is giving correct results sometimes and sometimes it is giving the wrong results. Need Help...Thank you

**app.e2e-spec.ts:**

```js
import {AppPage} from "./app.po";
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';
import {browser, by, element, protractor} from "protractor";


describe('The Right Doctor Test Report ', function() {
    let page: AppPage;
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

    let linksArray:string[]=[];
    let imagesArray:string[]=[];
    let videosArray:string[]=[];
    let socialArray:string[]=[];
    beforeEach(() => {
        page = new AppPage();
    });

    it('Get All Home Page Test ', () => {
       /* page.navigateTo();*/
        browser.get('http://localhost:4200/');
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.sleep(10000);
        //find all links
        let linkCount = element.all(by.css('.testChecking'));
        //here you click each of the links:
        linkCount.each(function(elem,index){
            elem.getAttribute('href').then(function(link){
                if(link!=null)
                    linksArray.push(link);
            });
        });
    });

        it('Single Video Page Test Cases: ', () => {
            for(let i=0;i<linksArray.length;i++) {
                browser.get(linksArray[i]).then(()=> {
                    // total views should be greater than 100
//expect(element(by.css('.sviews')).getText()).not.toBeLessThan(100);
expect(parseInt(element(by.css('.sviews')).getText())).not.toBeLessThan(100);
                });
                browser.sleep(1000);
            }
        });

});
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```js
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    // For Travis CI only
    chromeOptions: {
      binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN,
      args: ['--no-sandbox']
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
          savePath: './screenshots/'
        })
    );
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: './screenshots/',
      screenshotsFolder: 'images',
      takeScreenshots: true,
      consolidateAll: true,
      cleanDestination: true,
      //takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
      //showPassed: false,
      fileName: 'TestReport'
    }));
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

If I don't use parseInt then:

53 views and 111 views
[image]

40 views and 200 views
[image]

111 views and 47 views
[image]

40 views and 50 views
[image]

If I write parseInt then below result is displaying.
**Output:**

138 views and 340 views
[image]

47 views and 340 views
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your are expecting `.getText()` to return a string. It actually returns a promise that needs to be resolved. Using [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to resolve the promise before testing it should give you the results you need.

```
let str = await element(by.css('.sviews')).getText();
let num = parseInt(str);
await expect(num).not.toBeLessThan(100);
```

Another idea that could work is to check the length and not the number. Any number less than 100 will be 1 or 2 digits long while greater than 100 will be 3 digits or more. The regex string `.{3,}` will only pass if the string 3 or more characters.

```
expect(element(by.css('.sviews')).getText()).toMatch(/.{3,}/);
```

Comment: If I use the second solution it is also giving the results as above pictures.
 
I tried this one also... 

`expect(element(by.css('.sviews')).getText()).toMatch(/^[0-9]{3,}$/);`

Comment: Below code is giving syntax error If I use directly.


`let str = await element(by.css('.sviews')).getText(); let num = parseInt(str); await expect(num).not.toBeLessThan(100);`


It is passing all failed and passed conditions If I use it as a function like below code. 


`asyncCall();`
`async function asyncCall() { 
console.log('calling');
let str = await element(by.css('.sviews')).getText(); let num = parseInt(str); console.log(num); 
await expect(num).not.toBeLessThan(100);
}`

Comment: @DeveloperTeam What is the output of `console.log($('.sviews').getText())` Maybe the output is slightly different than expected?

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure your string will always be in the form of an integer you could use the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) operator to simplify your code a little instead of `parseInt`. You could just do this

```
element(by.css('.sviews')).getText()
    .then(function(num) {
        expect(+num).not.toBeLessThan(100);
    });
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for  reply , but still its not showing proper count , some times its showing proper count and some times its not showing anything .